# Android Studio] KOTLIN Navigation Bar

Tags: android, kotlin

Hey I'm following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8MbOjBCu0o&t=631s)

when I try to do the step 9:53 my 'bottom_navigation' is showing an error (it's red) and alt + enter shows 'create abstract ...'. I've followed every step and on main_activity named it bottom_navigation too so I'm not sure why it's not catching it. Also, 10:00, my 'it' is in red and shows an error too. Apart from that everything is working fine. Any advice? thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: kotlin synthetics is deprecated in favor of view binding. Read this [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. open your build gradle app

[image: see this]

2. add this line :

   ```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'  <<<<-----------
   ```

   }

Then sync..

let me know if this works !! and approve it :)